# Mac chat client for Facebook

Tags: osx, chat, facebook

I’m looking for a Mac chat client that supports Facebook.

Features:

- Ability to view all Facebook messages previously exchanged with a contact (this is where Adium and iMessage fall short)
- Must be a desktop client, not a web app
- Pop-up notifications when a message is received

Bonus features:

- Ability to suppress Facebook’s message read feature
- Alerts when a selected contact comes online
- Ability to message Google Talk users
- Ability to float on top of other windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [**Astro**](http://astroim.com/#/hero). This is the only Facebook client that I'm aware of that lets you access previous messages. Astro is a desktop client and uses OS X notifications for new messages.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried Flamingo?
I think it's close to what you've listed:

- it's a native app
- it's integrated with OSX's notifications
- it supports Hangouts too
- Unfortunately it does not support syncing history and messages sent from other clients because of limitations of Facebook's API (see [this FAQ](http://flamingo.im/faq/#history-sync))

If you're using Skype, you could connect Facebook to it - https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA11065/can-i-keep-in-touch-with-my-facebook-friends-in-skype-for-mac-os-x

I'm using Trillian, but it does not sync the history too (I guess it's the same reason as with Flamingo)

Comment: Thanks for helping out, Boyan! But could you please take a look at [our discussion on what makes an answer high quality](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/356/185), and see if you can [edit] some of the improvements into your answer? Answers here on SR should explicitly state how the recommended product matches each requirement, and if possible include own experiences made with.

Comment: I don't believe that Skype allows you to view messages that were sent offline. I haven't tried Flamingo because I don't want to spend $13 unless I know it meets my requirements

Comment: Sorry I edited my answer - it's my first answer so I'm not sure it's written how it's supposed to be. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks heaps for your answer. Its especially interesting to learn that the Facebook API limits viewing of past messages

Comment: I don't think Facebook API limits access to older messages, just that most clients use Jabber which has no access to older messages —cc @Casebash